# Gzip compression using boost library

Tags: c++11, boost, compression

I want a compress write a program which can compress directory and all its files in a .gz file. I have tried using using gzip filter but I dont know how can I add directory and multiple files. Also I would like to uncompress the same.

Comment: .gz (gzip) only allows you to compress ONE (1) file.

Answer (score 1):

`gzip` by itself only compresses a single stream of data with no assumed structure. To archive directories using gzip, it is most commonly combined with `tar`, which has the ability to compress using gzip built in. I'm sure you have seen those sorts of files, which end in `.tar.gz`. You can probably find a library that processes those files.